# Autodesk Data Management webhooks firing events two times?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-webhooks

I'm receiving two similar events in my server. I'm sendig a response with status 201, but it doesn't solve the problem (after that, i was receiving 4 similar events). The only difference between the events are two fields in the headers (*X-Adsk-Delivery-Id* and *X-Forwarded-For*).
The events are received exactly at the same moment (less than a second of difference).
It's by default launching two events?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you send a 2xx response immediately when you receive the callbacks?

Our service would send another callback if it doesn't get a response within 6 seconds so if you got other workflows to finish before sending responses be sure to process them asynchronously.

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/basics/#callback) for details:

> Webhooks guarantees at least once delivery. When the event occurs, the webhooks service sends a payload to the callback URL as an HTTP POST request. The webhook service expects a 2xx response to the HTTP POST request. The response must be received within 6 seconds. A non-2xx response is considered an error. In the event of an error, the webhook service will retry immediately, in 15 minutes, and 45 minutes thereafter. The webhook service retries for 48 hours and disables the webhook if the callback does not succeed during this time. You may need to reconfigure your webhooks if they are disabled.

Comment: Yes, I send the response before managing the event, Could it be a delay error with ngrok? The response times that their UI shows are correct...

Comment: Could be - try cloud serverless patterns such as lambda functions (eliminating the latency issue) to trap the callback (and push to a queue for processing etc.) and respond with a 2xx immediately.

Comment: It's still sending 2 events, I don't understand why, but i have to deal with it. I'll probably discard one of them or something like that...

Comment: The problem happend same with me today when I'm try investigate webhook to trigger the event `dm.event.added` from BIM360, from server side it call more than two time to webhook. And when I check again event I saw a diffrence update between single file and composite design. 
- With Single file design, sometime it call a composite design together with event of file depend
- With Composite Design file, it just update trigger with main file only.